# How to patch small anchor holes in plaster wall and potentially reinstall anchors?

Tags: plaster, fastener, patch

[image: plaster holes]
We had a hook next to the one that you see in the picture. There was a towel on the hook and someone grabbed the towel and hung all of their weight on it and basically the anchors pulled out of the plaster wall.

The two big holes above the two small holes are from the anchors that held the hooks. The existing anchors don’t fit in the holes anymore. I can use a bigger anchor because the screw that come with the hook will be too small for the anchors.

Is there a way for me to patch the existing holes and then drill into them again to install anchors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is just a towel rack, not a catwalk in a power plant or something like that, I see no harm in tinkering a bit.

Very easy fix, use small zinc auger type anchors, they make a bigger hole in the drywall for a smaller screw, so these should work in the existing holes:

[image: auger anchor]

You want the zinc ones since you might want to unscrew this at some time.

Comment: I love these types of anchors but the wall is plaster...

Comment: I think those will work fine in plaster and wood lath.

Comment: I’m concerned that while I’m screwing in the insert it will just break the plaster...

Comment: If you want to be really careful, drill out the hole to the approximate diameter of the anchor shaft, and spray the plaster with water before.  Of course drive the anchor with a plain screwdriver rather than a power tool for better control, it shouldn't take much torque.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Luckily for me the one of the anchor sizes was the perfect size. It was just wider than the hole. I was able to screw in the insert and use the original screw that came with the hook.  Great suggestion!